# How do I show an entire announcement?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Is there a way to do it without having to write code? I'm wanting each of my announcements on on my default landing page to show its entire contents.

Comment: Also, I'm not very proficient in Sharepoint. I don't know how create web parts. I only know how to add ones that exist already.

Comment: Which verison of SP are we talking about? 07? 10? 13?

Comment: Foundation 2010

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the steps below and it works, so follow the below steps:

1.Go into the Announcements section by clicking on the title.
2.Create a new view based on the existing default. I called mine "All items with Body"
3.Make sure the 'body' column is checked, and select "Newsletter" under Style.
4.Go back to your main page, and select 'edit shared web part' for the announcements section you're working on.
5.Change the view to be the new view you just created and click OK.

You will need to play with the view settings to make it look the way you want.

Comment: I will definitely be giving these a try next week. Thanks Rounn!

Comment: When I change the view, none of my announcements show up. What do you think it could be? I should qualify my statement. The entire announcement shows up on the announcements page, but at the home page, nothing shows up at all.

Comment: Okay, I got all the items back, but I had to change it back to Default style from Newsletter style. Newsletter style had it all jacked up for me. Any of the other styles seemed to mess it up on my home page...